# Get the index of the parent (belonging to a particular class only ) on clicking of button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list with a set of list elements having different class names.

When I click on the play button in the below script , I want to get the index of it's parent (li) .

However, the `.index()` method gives the index of the `li` in the `ul` . I need the index as a particular class. For example, I have 2 'play' buttons. If I click on the second 'play' button, I need to print an index of 1 , not the actual index from the list.

```js
$('.audio_btn').unbind('click');
$('.audio_btn').bind('click', function(event){
    alert($(this).parents('.audio').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="audio"><input type="button" class="audio_btn" value="play"></li>
    <li class="video">My Video</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="audio"><input type="button" class="audio_btn" value="play"></li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is expected result if you have more than one UL element? Should index be relative to UL parent or document?

Comment: @A.Wolff : The scenario has only one UL element. It would help if you can point out the difference between having the index relative to the UL parent and the document.

Comment: If you have only one UL element, it doesn't matter. If you would have more than one, you could wish to get index relative to parent UL, not all the `.audio` elements in document, see e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/7pfyyamp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$('.audio')` collection as the source for index to be determined

```js
$('.audio_btn').unbind('click');
$('.audio_btn').bind('click', function(event) {
  console.log($('.audio').index($(this).parents('.audio')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="text">My Text</li>
  <li class="audio">
    <input type="button" class="audio_btn" value="play">
  </li>
  <li class="video">My Video</li>
  <li class="text">My Text</li>
  <li class="text">My Text</li>
  <li class="text">My Text</li>
  <li class="audio">
    <input type="button" class="audio_btn" value="play">
  </li>
  <li class="text">My Text</li>
  <li class="text">My Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @AmmarCSE! That works! Will accept this as the answer after the timeout.

Comment: Don't use bind and unbind. It's way depricated

Comment: @Mateutek : when did bind get deprecated? It was `live()` that got deprecated AFAIK ?

Comment: @harsha, the better approach now is to use on() and off()

Comment: @harsha Yeah exactly but bind is going to be depricated too.
As the documentation states. "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: @Mateutek bind/unbind has been superseeded by on/off but (still) not deprecated. BTW, still in jQ 3.0

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the `.audio` selector to the index method :

```js
$('.audio_btn').unbind('click');
$('.audio_btn').bind('click', function(event){
    alert($(this).parents('.audio').index('.audio'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="audio"><input type="button" class="audio_btn" value="play"></li>
    <li class="video">My Video</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="audio"><input type="button" class="audio_btn" value="play"></li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
    <li class="text">My Text</li>
</ul>
```

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/index/